# Is there a way to highlight TODO's on the QtCreator IDE?

Tags: qt, plugins, qt-creator, todo

I am "refactoring" and improving some lines of code in a forked GitHub project (a Qt calculator), using the Qt-Creator IDE;

Therefore, I need a *"TO-DO plugin"* (to highlight some comments, those I am going to put next to the changed lines of code).

Actually, I have already tried the *Dmitry Savchenko*'s TO-DO plugin (it can be found and installed in Help -> About Plugins -> Utilities menu), however it doesn't work at all, such as it is not installed;

Just appears a "To-Do Entries" panel, next to the debugger console, that doesn't show anything up (even trying to write "TO-DO" at the beginning of some comments).

Comment: That plugin works fine for me... I'm on QtC 4.10 (RC1) but it has worked for at least several versions back. There are a few config settings that show up on the Options -> To-Do panel after plugin is activated (and Creator restarted), have you checked those?  What Creator version? Language?  Could be a bug...

Comment: Yes, I have checked that control panel. The version is _Qt Creator 4.5.2, Based on Qt 5.9.5 (GCC 7.3.0, 64 bit)_ (copy-pasted from the system information page) and I am coding in C++